# Date format - Logic error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a date saved to the `var mydate`. When i print that i get the string equivalent of `Tue Feb 10 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`.

Now i need to format the `var mydate` so it will display the date as `Tue Feb 10 2009`.

The code;

```
var today = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                var mydate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - today.getDay());
```

When i display `my date`, i got the string equivalent of `Tue Feb 10 2009 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)`. But what i want is this `Tue Feb 10 2009`. How can i do this by formatting `var my date` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `myDate.toDateString()`?

Here's an example:

```
> new Date().toDateString()
"Fri Feb 22 2013"
```

Also have a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

One way that you could achieve this is by creating a custom date (by creating a new class called `myDate` which extends Date) and override the `.toString()` method. That it returns the information in the format you desire.

Answer (score 1):

From your code I am assuming you are using the jQuery date picker from http://www.kelvinluck.com.

Assuming you are, and you are using the Date class provided with the package you can do something like this:

```
    //Date.format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';
    Date.format = 'D M dd yyyy';
    //Tue Feb 10 2009
    $('.date-picker').datePicker({
        startDate:'01/01/2001'
        //other options here..
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are good and simple libraries to format dates easily.
You can try this one:
http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/